# Date Addition using excluding weekends (Friday) in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I Have a code which gives in "H5" cell excluding Fridays but it refers from "H4". And I need "H4" Also ***excluding Fridays.***

```
Sub DateAddition()

Range("H4").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(Range("H4").Value))

Range("H5").Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(Range("H4").Value, 1, 16, 0)

End Sub
```

*I've tried using Like this Unfortunately Doesn't work.*

```
Range("H4").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(Range("H4").Value, 1, 16, 0))
```

I Know if a change given to this line i can make it. But Dont Know the code

```
Range("H4").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(Range("H4").Value))
```

***I need "H4" Cell out put to be a date must exclude Fridays***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same as you did for H5. The [WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.workday_intl) is already adding one day (given by the second parameter which is `1`) so you don't need to use `DateAdd`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DateAddition()
    Range("H4").Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(Range("H4").Value, 1, 16, 0)
    Range("H5").Value = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay_Intl(Range("H4").Value, 1, 16, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: How About Subtracting the date

Comment: @AfzalAshraf You should really read the documentation if I already give you the direct link: *"Days - The number of workdays before or after the start_date. A positive value yields a future date; a negative value yields a past date; a 0 (zero) value yields the start_date. Day-offset is truncated to an integer."*

Comment: I'm Sorry I didn't Check that. But Now I understood. You are very Kind and Helpful!